# Printing grails error messages with custom arguments

Tags: validation, grails

So I want to use the standard format for error messages. I don't want to specify other than default codes.

Example:

```
domain.property.minSize.notmet=I like purple {?}.
```

So I am looping through my errors:

```
domain.errors.fieldErrors.each {
    println g.message(error: it, args: ['bunnies'])
}
```

This doesn't work correctly because I think the first x arguments are already defined because of the default error message, and that number changes depending on what the error is. How can I specify arguments to the standard error codes without struggling to know what number `'?'` should be?

So I've gone down this road, hopefully there isn't some way easier option. I am overriding the messageSource bean with my own implementation that simply adds a method:

```
public class MessageSource extends PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource implements GrailsApplicationAware, PluginManagerAware, InitializingBean  {

    public final String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Object[] args, Locale locale)
            throws NoSuchMessageException {

        Object[] arguments;
        if (args == null) {
            arguments = resolvable.getArguments();
        } else {
            arguments = args;
        }
        String[] codes = resolvable.getCodes();
        if (codes == null) {
            codes = new String[0];
        }
        for (String code : codes) {
            String msg = getMessageInternal(code, arguments, locale);
            if (msg != null) {
                return msg;
            }
        }
        String defaultMessage = resolvable.getDefaultMessage();
        if (defaultMessage != null) {
            return renderDefaultMessage(defaultMessage, arguments, locale);
        }
        if (codes.length > 0) {
            String fallback = getDefaultMessage(codes[0]);
            if (fallback != null) {
                return fallback;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchMessageException(codes.length > 0 ? codes[codes.length - 1] : null, locale);
    }
}
```

This is really almost an exact copy of one of the other methods, that I just modified to take in arguments. The problem I am having with this is that it never finds my error message, always falling back to default. `msg` is always null.

Edit: Just tried it with the standard method and the same is true with `msg` always being null.

Comment: Probably you will need to use the messageSource bean.

Comment: *that number changes depending on what the error is* - I think the number changes based on the # of `args` sent to `message` instead. In your example it will always be `{0}` hence `I like purple {0}` unless otherwise I am referring something completely out of the topic without understanding the question.

Comment: Unfortunately @dmahapatro that isn't the case. There are default arguments. The number of default arguments changes based on what error message it is.

Comment: The problem is that the default grails code is not designed to take arguments when getting an error message from a fieldError.

Comment: @JamesKleeh you're correct. ValidationTagLib just ignore if you pass arguments. You can try to override `g.message` to use your new `getMessage()` method.

Comment: Jim, I am still in a grey area about this. The way I suggested above works for me. Help me understand what am I missing and what your objective is. I would be glad to understand the fact.

Comment: Are you using a fieldError? It works just fine when you specify the code directly.

Comment: So there is something I'm not doing right when using this class. It actually finds my message when I don't override it, so there is something I am missing.